# How to use FontAwesome without classes and without Bootstrap in a Rails project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to use [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in my Rails project but **without** Bootstrap or having to use classes à la `<i class="icon-camera-retro"></i>`.

I dropped all the 5 font files into my folder `/assets/fonts` and then in my `base.css` I do this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
  url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I want to do something like this:

```
<span class="foo">Text</span>

.foo:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\2022";
}
```

The problem is it's not working at all.

Can anybody tell me how it's done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your code is fine, I have it working the same:

```
span:before {
content: "\f059";
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
font-size: 120%;
}
```

I have a question icon ( icon-question-sign - `&#xf059;`)

My question to you is what is this?

*content: "\2022";*

I do no see it in here...might be your answer..:

[FontAwesome Sheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/)

icon-camera-retro should be:

**content: "\f083";**

Comment: OK, thanks. I did a silly mistake in my css (I was referencing the wrong file). Your solution helped me, though, so I marked it as correct.